# Which is better for performance

Tags: performance, vb6

Recently I had to write a function that compares a combobox list of items to a record set from a database. After finishing the work i'm wondering what would be better for performance.

Solution 1

```
foreach item in combobox1
  foreach record in recordset
    if item.id = record["id"] 
        foundInCombo = true
        exit for
    end if
   Next record
   if foundInCombo = false
       combobox1.removeitem(item)
   end if
Next item
```

Solution 2

```
foreach item in combobox1
  foreach record in recordset
    if item.id = record["id"] 
        foundInCombo = true
        recordset.remove(record)
        exit for
    end if
   Next record
   if foundInCombo = false
       combobox1.removeitem(item)
   end if
Next item
```

This is pseudo code of course, and I know in modern languages there is much better ways to do this, but it was in VB6 and i'm just curious if the overhead in removing of the record from the record set offsets the less amounts of iterations of the entire loop.

**Update:**
In case anyone is learning an older language and working in legacy code with limited ability to change it I made some test based on the comments below, and found it was not much of a difference for the first 25 items, but once i got around 100 it started to have performance gains by removing the item.

Comment: if both lists were sorted you could optimize nicely, but removing is probably slower than going through entire list.

Comment: I think that the best way is to reload ComboBox from recordset.

Comment: I think a bit more info is needed. What are you trying to accomplish? Should the combo have the same items as the recordset at the end? Or does the combo have a subset of what's in the recordset? The speed increase of removing records would depend on how many records are in the recordset vs. number of items in the combo. If there's 10 items in the combo and 1000 records in the recordset then removing 10 records isn't going to make much of a difference in how long it takes to iterate the recordset.

Comment: @Marc Thanks I did some testing based on this and recorded the results for others in my group. It was not much of  a difference for the first 25 items which is more then would probably be in their for my casem but once i got around 100 it started to have performance gains by removing the item. Thank you for the help.